# Rotate instance with offset in Geo Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I just created this animation

[image]

But I did it with individual separate objects and I'm finding a way to get animation like this with geo node for more convenient and better performance.Like making instances of one object and rotating it with offset

I'm very very much beginner at geo node so don't know how to setup it and I thought to take help if anyone want to do

Thank you :)

Comment: Please show your node setup, that does the animation.

Comment: Be aware, that we can manipulate keyframed animation with geo nodes yet. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

but tbh if you wanna do animations more "natural" like in this animation, animation nodes would be the better choice in the moment, because it supports things like "bouncing" via nodes. In GN you have to do this manually by hand with this float curve node.

Comment: Thank you , this can solved my problem but let me also try with animation nodes
Thank you for your time :)